# How to keep an integral number float in Lua 5.3

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

```
print(2^62)
print(2^63)
print(2^64)
```

In Lua 5.2, all numbers are doubles. The output of the above code is:

```
4.6116860184274e+18
9.2233720368548e+18
1.844674407371e+19
```

Lua 5.3 has support for integers and does automatic conversion between integer and float representation. The same code outputs:

```
4611686018427387904
-9223372036854775808
0
```

I want to get the float result. `2.0^64` works, but what if it's not a literal:

```
local n = io.read("*n")  --user input 2
print(n^64)
```

One possible solution is to divide the number by `1`:  `(n/1)^64` because in `/` division , the operands are always converted to float, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Tested on [Lua 5.3.0 (work2)](https://github.com/lua/lua).

Comment: There are no more elegant solutions in Lua after splitting numbers to floats and integers :(  You must **always** think carefully about number's datatype.  No more easiness of programming...

Comment: +1 The best "feature" of Lua was that the programmer needs minimal or no special casing when learning or using the language. I think that's marred by 5.3's introduction of 2 types of numbers :(

Comment: That's a little bit disappointed, I wonder if they could consider a new way for representing numbers like `42i` or `42f`.

Comment: In your above example change it so `n = 2.0`?

Comment: @Eidola My example is not clear, I was trying to say `n` is not a literal, like a number from user input. Updated.

Comment: @YuHao, 42i -> 42, 42f -> 42.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`io.read("*n")` always returns a float. So no surprises there.

If you need to convert an integer to a float, add `0.0` to it.